# How to configure WiFi using the commandline?

Tags: wifi

How do I connect my Pi running the latest Raspberry Pi OS Lite to my Access Point with only the commandline available?

This means I have either access to keyboard and display or I have SSH setup and have a LAN connection. I think for both cases have the same answer.

Debian 12 (bookworm)

When I use raspi-config I just get:

`There was an error running option S1 Wireless LAN`

I was able to guess the problem, but no thanks to the error-message.
`raspi-config` wants you to just enter the wireless info and does not return a helpful error message if the given config was incorrect.

What I am looking for is something like the following pseudo-steps:

1. Check if your WiFi is active and if it is not, then activate it with this command:
   `if $(wifi-is-off) then turn-wifi-on`
2. List available SSID's (only show 2.4 GHz SSID's):
   `nmcli list ssid`
3. Connect to WiFi and get prompted for the password (or write it down in some file): `nmcli connect $MY_SSID`
4. Check if wifi is connected: `some command to check wifi status`
5. Check for internet connectivity: `curl -Is  http://www.google.com | head -n 1`

I am guessing the command line interface of the network manager `nmcli` is needed based on the comments. Maybe `systemd-networkd` ?

Comment: it looks like from bookworm onwards one has to use the Raspberry Pi Imager to achieve wireless conecctivity at boot time.

Comment: It seems you've got keyboard and monitor access to your Pi - correct? If so, you'll have to set up networking "from scratch" using the `nmcli` app. `dhcpcd` has been deprecated, and removed from the default install - you can install it with `apt`, but I've not tried to set it up on 'bookworm'.

Comment: `nmcli` ... or `nmtui` if you're that way inclined